# solving simultaneous equations by elimination method (not matrix or any software)

Tags: linear-algebra

I know solving simultaneous equations if there is only 2 equations (for 2 unknowns) or 3 equations (for 3 unknowns). But things become messy if you have given a task to solve 5 equations with 5 unknowns using only elimination method (not using any matrix method or computer software).

Can someone show to students here how to do it or just give tips/techniques so we can arrive at the same answer (if it was given)? This kind of problems can be encounter by dealing with Kirchhoff's laws.

For example you were given 2 KCL equations and 3 KVL equations:

> > $I_1 - I_2 - I_3 = 0$
> >
> > $I_3 - I_4 - I_5 = 0$
> >
> > $-4I_1 - 6I_2 = -15$
> >
> > $6I_2 - I_3 - 3I_4 = 0$
> >
> > $3I_4 - 2I_5 = 10$

I tried many solutions but i can't get the correct answer which is :

> > $I_1 = 1.89$
> >
> > $I_2 = 1.24$
> >
> > $I_3 = 0.65$
> >
> > $I_4 = 2.26$
> >
> > $I_5 = -1.61$

Showing solutions or providing useful tips / techniques are very much appreciated especially by students here.

I am new here so please help me to make this question valuable and put this in a right tag. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use matrices?  Part of their purpose is to make these computations easier.  If you really want to avoid matrices you can do everything you would do with matrices but just write a system of equations instead, since they're essentially the same thing.  That is, Gaussian elimination.

Comment: the requirement in my homework is to solve this by using elimination by substitution only. you are right that part of the purpose of matrices to simplify this kind of messy equations but i need to stick to the requirement. thank you for appreciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Gauss elimination without matrix
(1) The first equation should be the only one that contains $I_1$(so you have to multiply the first one by 4 and add it to the third one)
(2) Do the same with the four equations I.e. the first should be the only one that contains $I_2$
(3) Repeat this process till the last equation contains only $I_5$
(4) Back substitution

> > $I_1 - I_2 - I_3 = 0$
> >     $I_3 - I_4 - I_5 = 0$
> >     $-4I_1 - 6I_2 = -15$
> >     $6I_2 - I_3 - 3I_4 = 0$
> >     $3I_4 - 2I_5 = 10$
> >     (1) One equation contains I1
> >     $I_1 - I_2 - I_3 = 0$
> >     $I_3 - I_4 - I_5 = 0$
> >     $-10I_2 - 4I_3 = -15$
> >     $6I_2 - I_3 - 3I_4 = 0$
> >     $3I_4 - 2I_5 = 10$
> >     (2) One equation(from the remaining 4) contains I2
> >     $I_1 - I_2 - I_3 = 0$
> >     $I_3 - I_4 - I_5 = 0$
> >     $-10I_2 - 4I_3 = -15$
> >     $-17 I_3 - 15I_4 = -45$
> >     $3I_4 - 2I_5 = 10$
> >     rearrange them
> >     $I_1 - I_2 - I_3 = 0$
> >     $-10I_2 - 4I_3 = -15$
> >     $I_3 - I_4 - I_5 = 0$
> >     $-17 I_3 - 15I_4 = -45$
> >     $3I_4 - 2I_5 = 10$
> >     (2) One equation(from the remaining 3) contains I3
> >     $I_1 - I_2 - I_3 = 0$
> >     $-10I_2 - 4I_3 = -15$
> >     $I_3 - I_4 - I_5 = 0$
> >     $-32 I_4 - 17I_5 = -45$
> >     $3I_4 - 2I_5 = 10$
> >     (2) One equation(from the remaining 2) contains I4 continue

Comment: how could i do that? when i try to eliminate I1 in 3rd equation, it came to have I2. if would make equation 1 to be the one with only I2, it will bring I1 back to the 3rd equation??

Comment: Good, now the first is the only one that contains I1, now go to the third and fourth one contains I2 try to eliminate I2 from one of them and continue

Comment: i have now I1- I2 - I3 = 0 ;
I3 - I4 - I5 = 0 ;
-34I3 - 30I4 = -15 ;
3I4 - 2I5 = 10 ;

what should i do next? eliminate I4 to -34I3 - 30I4 = -15 and
3I4 - 2I5 = 10 ??

Comment: Give me minutes and i will solve it for you

Comment: i've got I5 = -2.59 and it does not fit the correct answer. what's my mistake?

Comment: may be there are some numbers wrong during calculations, but the important thing the way you go through, elimination of unkowns one next one till you get one equation with one variable and then back substitution

Comment: @nicy12 do you want me to revise it

Comment: Thank You very very very very very much!!!! i started solving and finding ways to answer it 2 days ago and you are the ONLY one who understand my thoughts. thank you very much semsem! i got the correct answer! thank you very much! :)

Comment: Glad to help out. Thanks for the kind words, the vote of confidence, and of course the "acceptance"

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: You say that you have to use elimination by substitution and cannot use matrix methods; however, using Gaussian elimination on a matrix *is* exactly elimination by substitution. You can write everything out in long form if you like, but the algorithm for finding the solution is the same.

I believe [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) is what you are looking for. The problem is a linear system, which is what matrix notation is shorthand for, so that really is the way to go. (Also, elimination is what I'd consider a "matrix method.")

The system you have is below. The linked page will walk you through the steps on how to carry out the elimination.

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
-6 & -6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 6 & -1 & -3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & -2
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
I_1 \\ I_2 \\ I_3 \\ I_4 \\ I_5
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 0 \\ -15 \\ 0 \\ 10
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: Gaussian elimination is considered to be "matrix method" and that's not i am looking for. the requirement is to solved it using "elimination by substitution method" i'll really appreciate if you can provide it. thanks